# Current to Voltage Converter in CMOS

Tags: operational-amplifier, cmos, vlsi

If I want to use a 2-stage opamp for the current to voltage converter application, How should I check for the stability of the circuit? Will it need any kind of stability correction? An uncompensated 2- stage opamp is unstable as voltage amplifier with feedback.[image]

Comment: *An uncompensated 2- stage opamp is unstable as voltage amplifier with feedback* **No** it is not, it depends on the design (and external load) if it is stable or not. The answer to your question is: you do a **stability analysis**,  Generally learning this is part of what you would need to learn to become a IC / circuit designer, explaining it here goes too far making this question "too broad". Fortunately there is plenty about that to be found in books and internet, for example: http://www.ti.com/lit/an/sloa020a/sloa020a.pdf Also, this is unrelated to "CMOS" nor "VLSI".

Comment: in particular, the noise gain of that stage is ONE, so the transient performance with Av = +1 is important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If, as you said, an uncompensated 2-stage amplifier is unstable then you have answered your own about whether or not you need compensation.

To check for stability, I would create a circuit simulation at the transistor level that includes all relevant parasitic capacitances and resistances. Then perform an ac simulation out to a few megahertz, looking for changes in gain. You might also want to run transient simulations while slowly sweeping the frequency. Be sure to do this for a range of dc bias conditions.